# Flutter Scroll Physics Jumps to End of or Top of the list

Tags: flutter

I'm using `ListView.builder` in horizontal side and `SingleChildScrollView` in vertical side in a page. When I touch ListView.builder part in the app to scroll horizontally, it jumps to end of list and does not smoothly scroll a bit to left or right. Same happens when the scroll is end of the list When I touch, it suddenly jumps to the start point of list items.

I tried different scroll physics in order to fix this issue and **it is not related** to **bouncing scroll physics**.

```
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: ScrollController(),
                itemCount: 8,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                    child: ProductCard2(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

[Here is the video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm5IFuVywtQ) to demonstrate what is happening.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the full code of Widget build:

```
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 9,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 8,
                controller: scrollController1,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                    child: StoryWidget(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: CustomPageViewSlider(pageController: pageController),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                'Yeni Ürünler',
                style: AppTextStyles().boldTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: scrollController2,
                itemCount: 8,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                    child: ProductCard2(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                'Fırsat Ürünleri',
                style: AppTextStyles().boldTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: scrollController3,
                itemCount: 8,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                    child: ProductCard3(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

In the page, as you see there is one `SingleChildScrollView` to make vertical scroll, one `PageController` for slider, 2 different horizontal scrollers for products.

```
  final ScrollController scrollController1 = ScrollController();
  final ScrollController scrollController2 = ScrollController();
  final ScrollController scrollController3 = ScrollController();
```

And I made them final.

**UPDATE NUMBER 2:**

I added the homeView that holds WelcomeView (which contains listviewbuilder & pageView widgets) FavoritesView (blank page) ProductsView (which includes a listview builder that triggers bug) and CompanyView (blank page)

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  List<Widget> widgetList = [
    WelcomeView(),
    FavoritesView(),
    ProductsView(),
    CompanyView(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var provider = Provider.of<StoreProvider>(context, listen: true);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors().backgroundColor,
      appBar: customizedAppBar(provider: provider),
      body: SafeArea(child: widgetList[provider.getSelectedIndex]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        elevation: 4.0,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            const Icon(
              Icons.shopping_bag,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            Positioned(
              child: Text(
                '${provider.getProductLength()}',
                style: AppTextStyles().boldTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 20,
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1),
            )
          ],
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 8),
            child: GNav(
              rippleColor: AppColors().rippleIndexColor,
              hoverColor: AppColors().hoverIndexColor,
              gap: 8,
              activeColor: AppColors().activeIndexColor,
              iconSize: 24,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
              color: Colors.black,
              // changable
              tabs: [
                GButton(
                  icon: AppCustomizations.firstIndexIcon,
                  text: AppLocalizationsTR.firstIndexText,
                ),
                GButton(
                  icon: AppCustomizations.secondIndexIcon,
                  text: AppLocalizationsTR.secondIndexText,
                ),
                GButton(
                  icon: AppCustomizations.thirdIndexIcon,
                  text: AppLocalizationsTR.thirdIndexText,
                ),
                GButton(
                  icon: AppCustomizations.fourthIndexIcon,
                  text: AppLocalizationsTR.fourthIndexText,
                ),
              ],
              selectedIndex: provider.selectedIndex,
              onTabChange: (index) {
                provider.changeSelectedIndex(index);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATE NUMBER 3:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kuyumculuk_example/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:kuyumculuk_example/widgets/product_card2.dart';
import 'package:kuyumculuk_example/widgets/product_card3.dart';
import 'package:kuyumculuk_example/widgets/slider.dart';
import 'package:kuyumculuk_example/widgets/story_widget.dart';

class WelcomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WelcomeView> createState() => _WelcomeViewState();
}

class _WelcomeViewState extends State<WelcomeView> {
  PageController pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.9);
  final ScrollController scrollController0 = ScrollController();
  final ScrollController scrollController1 = ScrollController();
  final ScrollController scrollController2 = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 9,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController0,
                itemCount: 8,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                    child: StoryWidget(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: CustomPageViewSlider(pageController: pageController),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                'Yeni Ürünler',
                style: AppTextStyles().boldTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: scrollController1,
                itemCount: 8,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                    child: ProductCard2(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                'Fırsat Ürünleri',
                style: AppTextStyles().boldTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: scrollController2,
                itemCount: 8,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                    child: ProductCard3(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomPageViewSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomPageViewSlider({
    Key? key,
    required this.pageController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final PageController pageController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
          child: SliderWidget(path: 'assets/slider/slider1.jpg'),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
          child: SliderWidget(path: 'assets/slider/slider2.jpg'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you tried it in release mode or debug mode

Comment: probably cause you are initializing the `ScrollController()` inside of the `ListView.Builder` try declaring and initializing it in the state class and then use it. i.e.
`final ScrollController controller = ScrollConstroller();` then use the `controller` in the `ListView.Builder`

Comment: Can you please show more code? Especially the one that wraps the container, I couldn't reproduce your issue

Comment: @omarhatem I updated the question and added more details.

Comment: @Roaa I updated the question and added more details.

Comment: @AlwayssBijoy I'm going to try it on release mode right now.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Is the jumping happening in all `ListView.builder`s or just the `CustomPageViewSlider`?

Comment: @Roaa They are only happening in ListView.builder. By the way, CustomPageViewSlider is basically returns PageView with 2 children and it has a controller.

Comment: Sorry but I still couldn't reproduce the issue, the behavior that's happening shouldn't be happening unless  you are doing some logic on the scroll controllers, is there any additional code outside your widget's build method? If so please include it.

Comment: @Roaa I appreciated your help. I added HomeView class which stands for bottombarView and a wrapper for other widgets in bottombar.

Comment: I’m trying to solve “unable to prepare iPhone for development” issue since it is suggested to run on a real device in release mode. Thank you for your time & efforts Roaa.

Comment: You're welcome. But I believe your issue won't be solved in release mode. Thank you for including the code, it was extra helpful, but I meant including the full widget code of the page where the issues are happening (maybe the `WelcomeView`? Anything surrounding the `Container` in your first code snippet

Comment: @Roaa I added the whole welcome_view.dart file inside question where below update number 3. I don't think I did something wrong since this is my standard usage for scroll physics in my other apps too.

Comment: Hi @ZahidTekbaş , I'm experiencing the same issue, did you ever manage to solve it? Does it still happen on a real device?

Comment: @JulienRipet sadly I could not manage to solve it.

Comment: Try to add addSemanticIndexes: false, to your listview.builder, it might fix the issue a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but someone may need this in the future.  When the contents of your List can get complicated or expandable themselves (like an ExpansionTile in a ListView), you'll probably need to eliminate bounce.  Not sure why, but it helps:

use this in your ListView.builder:

```
physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```